# bypassing a run-time error when no table to download (Excel Macro)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to download data from a table from numerous pages. (Table Query)

I run through an index on pages numbers - the problem is sometimes certin pages do not exist, and i receive a run-time error stating it cannot download the specific table.

is there a way to check if there is data 1st and than download it?

```
Dim i As Long
 Dim lastRow As Long 
For i = 120111 To 130000
 If (i Mod 100 = 11) Or (i Mod 100 = 21) Or (i Mod 100 = 31) Or (i Mod 100 = 41) Then 
lastRow = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row + 1
 With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _ "URL;http://...roundNum=" & i ,Destination:=Range("A" & lastRow)
```

Comment: Sure there is. Show us the code please.

Comment: sorry, meant to post a comment, not an answer, also realized I misread your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you din't post the actual url in the code I couldn't test this, but can't you just add an On Error Resume Next in there to skip the errors?  Or do you need to be able to actually track the ones that fail?  In such a case you could write an error handler.

```
Sub Download()
   Dim i As Long
   Dim lastRow As Long
   On Error Resume Next
   For i = 120111 To 130000
       If (i Mod 100 = 11) Or (i Mod 100 = 21) Or (i Mod 100 = 31) Or (i Mod 100 = 41)    Then
           lastRow = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row + 1
           With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="..." & i, Destination:=Range("A" & lastRow))
       End If
   Next i
End Sub
```